# Is there a proper way to encode a search from Google Cloud vs Locally Running a Python Script?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, urlencode, airtable

Airtable Python Wrapper is able to find a field using Airtable.MAtch when executed from the local machine, but It cannot make the match on Google Cloud.

Declared:

## -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

```
search = d['TITLE'] +  d['OFFICE']
    try: #THIS WONT WORK?? WHAT?
       record = airtable.match('mysearch', search)
       airtable.update(record['id'], d, typecast=True)
       print (' UPDATED ')       
   except:
       try: #NO PROBLEM INSERTING - TOO BAD ITS NOT CATCHING DUPLICATES
       airtable.insert(d,typecast=True)
       print (' INSERTED ')
```

Expected to find the search var in {mysearch} field. 
Works great on my machine. 
Will NOT find the match in GCM.

Comment: the console on gc shows 

(11, ' INSERTED ', u'Wrong Turn', ' - INSERT success counter:', 2) 

 on my mac it shows - 

11  UPDATED  Wrong Turn - UPDATE success counter: 2

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this is we have Fiverr, clearly.